# WP Shortcodes not returning content

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, themes

I am trying to set up a shortcode inside a template file.

I have the following setup:

As content in a WP page:

`[test]shortcode![/test]`

In functions.php:

```
function test( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<h1>'.$content.'</h1>';
}

add_shortcode("test", "test");
```

In the template.php of the page above:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[test]'); ?>
```

Nothing gets returned though. If I call `the_post()` and `the_content()` inside template.php the shortcode does display properly as a h1 but that's not the functionality I'm going for, I need to be able to plug the `[test]` shortcode in specific places.

Additionally, it seems that I can add hardcoded content in the function and it gets displayed, so most likely the $content variable is not returning any data ? What could be causing that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should echo the shortcode in order for it to work:

`<?php echo do_shortcode('[test]'); ?>`

Comment: sorry, I just missed the echo part in my post, fixed now. I am echoing it in my files though to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

refer this https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/do_shortcode/

you have to simply the echo the shortcode

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[test]'); ?>
```

Comment: my apologies, as I replied to Dimitar it was just a typo in my post here, I am echoing the do_shortcode in my files.

Answer (score 0):

You need to echoing the output. When using do_shortcode it will be functioning in wp-includes there is a file shortcodes.php. When triggering to function will return content to calling function. so code will be something like below:

```
 <?php echo do_shortcode('[test]'); ?>
```

Second thing,
your function argument have default `null` param so if you don't pass any content to shortcode then it will not display anything.

You need to do something like this

```
<?php echo do_shortcode('[test param="content_to_be_show"]'); ?>
```

Or if you want to pass between start tag and closing tag content as parameter you should do something like below:

```
function my_custom_shortcode_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
   return '<p>' . $content . '</p>';
}

add_shortcode( 'my_custom_shortcode', 'my_custom_shortcode_func' );
<?php echo do_shortcode('[my_custom_shortcode]<p>Hello this is from custom shortcode contents</p>[/my_custom_shortcode]'); ?>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply, however as mentioned in other comments that was just a typo in the post, I am echoing the do_shortcode in my file.

Comment: I don't have the need for arguments, but instead I want to display the content within the opening and closing statements of the shortcode as seen here - [test] display-this-content [/test]

Comment: I have updated my answer but in your question your callback function and shortcode name both is same so that may be an issue

Comment: thanks for your reply again, however this is still now working. For the record, the <p> inside the do_shortcode function in your example will be self generated right ? So my template file will only have <?php echo do_shortcode('[my_custom_shortcode]') ; ?> ?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't specified any content between test shortcode due to it you get empty result string. You need to write

```php
$strvar = 'Load String value here';
echo do_shortcode('[test]'.$strvar.'[/test]');
```

Above code gives result as `<h1>Load String value here</h1>`

`$strvar = get_the_content();`

Comment: So this code [test]shortcode![/test] is supposed to be editable via the WP interface, and I want to be able to display the content ("shortcode!" in this case) inside a template. I see what you're saying but I don't need to hardcode the content between the opening and closing shortcode tags, I want to call that content as a variable.

Comment: You can add your dynamic content via variable.  <?php echo do_shortcode('[test]'.$strvar.'[/test]'); ?> before this line set your dynamic content in $strvar.

Comment: I am not so sure how I'd go about that, as you can tell I don't know what I'm doing :) . And potentially there might be a lot of distinct dynamic content so I would still need a way to distinguish this inside the WP editor using open tag/close tag semantics, shortcodes seem the way to go atm

Comment: use $strvar= get_the_content(); which assign content of template page to variable. So, In WP Backend whatever you added for template page description is displayed.

Comment: I did this, however it ends up displaying all content on the page as opposed to only the content within the shortcode opening & closing tags. So when I edit the page in the WP editor, I now have something like this : Load string value [test] here [/test], and I want to only display the "here", how can I target that specifically ? get_the_content() seems to be returning everything

Comment: I think you're on the right track here btw, I just realized that the examples I took my code from were calling basing shortcodes while I'm calling an open/close shortcode so no wonder my initial code didn't work.